# Contar filas con MySQL

Tags: mysql

Necesito contar la cantidad de alumnos que existe en la TABLA alumnos por cada comuna, el total de comunas son siete y el total de alumnos son `1083`, necesito agrupar la cantidad de estudiantes por comuna, tengo la siguiente consulta pero me devuelve cero.

```
SELECT COUNT(id_alumno) AS cantidad, id_alumno
FROM tbl_alumnos
WHERE (
comuna='uno' AND comuna='dos' AND comuna='cuatro' AND comuna='cinco' AND comuna='seis' AND comuna='siete')
```

Reultado en la base de datos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, coloca un ejemplo del resultado que esperas obtener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola te recomiendo que pruebes cambiando tus AND pro OR, y quitar el id_alumno en el select.

```
SELECT COUNT(id_alumno) AS cantidad
FROM tbl_alumnos
WHERE comuna='uno' OR comuna='dos' OR comuna='cuatro' OR comuna='cinco' OR comuna='seis' OR comuna='siete'
```

Pero si requieres saber cuantos id_alumno estan en tu campo de comuna entonces agrega un GROUP BY

```
SELECT id_alumno, COUNT(id_alumno) AS cantidad 
FROM tbl_alumnos
WHERE comuna='uno' OR comuna='dos' OR comuna='cuatro' OR comuna='cinco' OR comuna='seis' OR comuna='siete'
GROUP BY id_alumno;
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que buscas esta consulta:

```
SELECT COUNT(id_alumno) AS cantidad 
FROM tbl_alumnos
GROUP BY comuna
```

Tu consulta no te devuelve nada porque en la clausula where estas imponiendo una condición imposible y es que al escribir la condicion *AND* estas imponiendo que los alumnos pertenezcan a la vez a todas esas comunas.

Answer (score 0):

Al ver el modelo que muestras en la imagen, veo que tienes la tabla de alumnos y comuna, por lo tanto, de acuerdo a tu pregunta estas deben tener alguna relación.

Siendo asi la consulta propuesta debería bastar para tu requerimiento

```
SELECT COUNT(tbl_alumnos.id_alumno) AS cantidad, comuna.name AS nombre_comuna
FROM tbl_alumnos LEFT JOIN tbl_comunas
ON tbl_alumnos.comuna_id = tbl_comunas.id
GROUP BY comuna.name
```

Retornandote

```
cantidad, nombre_comuna
10, comuna1
13, comuna2
etc...
```